Strategy and science behind determining which stocks to buy and invest in?
I'm starting to get into serious investing & I being new and inexprience I have questions regarding the decline & incline in stocks.
From my understanding and research, stocks increases and decreases based on supply and demmand. E.g. If more people want to buy a stock (demand) than sell it (supply), then the price moves up.
What if no one is buying a stock but the product or service is doing really well and selling a lot of services/products. Will the Stock increase and investors make money off of it. Since the stock is essentially a stock is a security that represents a fractional ownership in a company?
What are other variables to determine the best stock to invest in?

Unfortunately this is not a very good question for StackExchange. Whole libraries have been written on this topic. A good, actionable answer, can't be squeezed into a couple of paragraphs, unless you are willing to just have people's hot takes and opinions. Go to a library and seek out some of the books on the topic.

"What are other variables to determine the best stock to invest in?" This part of the question is definitely off-topic.

There are three ways for a stock owner to get cash out of that ownership - when they sell, when dividends are paid, or when the company is bought (or liquidated)

What if no one is buying a stock but the product or service is doing really well and selling a lot of services/products. Will the Stock increase and investors make money off of it. Since the stock is essentially a stock is a security that represents a fractional ownership in a company?

If you own a stock, you can only sell it for a price that someone else is willing to pay for it. If literally "no one is buying" then you cannot sell (I'm purposely ignoring market makers since this is an implausible scenario anyway)
In reality, with the exception of very illiquid stocks, there is always someone willing to buy at some price. That price might not reflect your view of the value of the stock, though.
That said, another way that investors can get cash from owning a stock is through dividends. A company can choose to (but is not required to) give some of its profits to shareholders instead of reinvesting them in the company. They are not really "profit" since a dividend lowers the price of the stock by the same amount (it's just transferring wealth, not creating it), but it is a way that you can get some money out without selling.
Finally, if a company gets acquired, then the existing shareholders will be entitled to their proportional amount of the amount paid for by the acquisition. That's the least common way for shareholders to get money out of their ownership, but it does happen.
